# Appmaker onClick or onValidate

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm new to Appmaker & for the most part, advanced web development. In 2016 I created a very rudimentary AMP stack page to be used in my employers office to take leads by phone and email, then afterward the estimators log in and claim them (place their name in a field) to remove them from available leads. I used Adobe CS5 Dreamweaver, which I'm sure you all know, no longer receives support for their PHP backend since PHP has had so much change. By the way, I know very little about PHP or Mysql, that's why I used Dreamweaver and I now move toward Appmaker. I also have no scripting background which is where I'm stuck at now, I think.

It took me awhile but I figured out how to setup Appmaker (We have no sysadmin, so I dug around until I got it working). I now know the basics of Appmaker, I even paid to take the Appmaker University Bootcamp course which did open my eyes to the correct way to build pages. Onto my issue...

Lead comes in and shows in main list, estimator views details and clicks one of two checkboxes. 1.) Pass (Not interested, do not list anymore in my view)
 2.) Claim (Move into claimed status, now owns this lead).

I have not started using database relations and I am unsure if this should be an instance where I should use them, but for now I just have Claim and Pass as Boolean table entries. I also have for each of these, accompanying table fields of Claim Date, Claim Estimator & Pass Date, Pass Estimator (Multiple Estimators can pass but only one can Claim).

I cannot figure out how to have the backend enter the date and user email upon clicking the Pass or Claim checkboxes.. I have tried adding stuff to onCLick and onValidate and nothing seems to work. Im confident I am looking in the wrong direction, please help.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this would be to use an `onBeforeSave` event at the model level.

```
if(record.Claim){
  record.ClaimEstimator = app.a.a.a[38].authority.getUsername();
  record.ClaimDate = new Date();
}else if(record.Pass){
  record.PassEstimator = app.a.a.a[38].authority.getUsername();
  record.PassDate = new Date();
}
```